# How to intercept and control saving a Django POST form?

Tags: django, post, google-maps-api-3, django-forms, django-views

When the user is required to fill his profile, he picks a city from the Google Places Autocomplete and posts the form, in the view I extract the city Id from the Google API based on the posted text (I use the same id as pk in my db) and try to extract a city from my db.

These are the models:

```
class City(models.Model):
     #extracted from the Google API
    city_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=150)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', primary_key=True) 
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, blank=True, null=True) 
    prof_pic = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='profile_pictures')
```

This is the view:

```
def createprofile(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST, instance=user)

        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)

            profile.user = user

            #brings back the city search result as text
            searched_city = request.POST['city']

            #brings back city ID from the Google API
            searched_city_id = population_script.get_city_json(searched_city.replace(" ", ""))['results'][0]['id']

            #If it's a valid city
            if searched_city_id != -1:
                city = City.objects.get(city_id = searched_city_id)

                profile.city = city#this is what I want to happen!

            else:
                return HttpResponse("There's no such city, please try a different query.")

            if 'prof_pic' in request.FILES:#now save the profile pic
                profile.prof_pic = request.FILES['prof_pic']
                print("PROF PIC IS: "  + profile.prof_pic.url)

            else:
                profile.prof_pic = 'images/anon.png'

            profile.save()

            if 'next' in request.GET:
                return redirect(request.GET['next'])

        else:
            print (user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()


    return render(request, 
 'excurj/createprofile.html', {'user_form':user_form, 'profile_form':profile_form})
```

However, I keep receiving an error that what's been posted is just text while the city needs to be a City object. I can save the profile pic ok though.

> Cannot assign "'Dubai - United Arab Emirates'": "UserProfile.city"
>   must be a "City" instance.

edit: these are the forms:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label = "First Name:",
        max_length = 80,
        required = True
        )

    last_name = forms.CharField(
        label = "Last Name:",
        max_length = 80,
        required = True,
        )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.CharField(
        label = "Your Current City:",
        max_length = 200,
        required = True,
        )
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('city','prof_pic', 'dob', 'sex', 'education', 'career', 'about_you', 
            'music_movies_books', )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by creating a new UserProfile field called `city_search_text` which  saves the searched text thus it of course does not return any error. I then receive it in the POST request and comfortable pull the proper city in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a `related_name` to the city field in the UserProfile.

Comment: @T K Sourab I tried but it goes through: `if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid(): ` and produces the above error, I tried assigning the city before this line with no luck.

Comment: Check your forms.

Answer (score 0):

I handled a similar issue by overriding my forms' clean method.  Something like the following will work:

```
def clean(self):

  # fix city problem
  if self.cleaned_data.get("city") is not None:
      self.cleaned_data['city'] = City.objects.get(id=self.cleaned_data.get("city"))

  return self.cleaned_data
```